# How to check if a contact of address book have name?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an application in Swift, and when I try get a contact of addressBook check if this have email, but when I try check if have a name, I get an error

```
  func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson person: ABRecordRef!) -> String {
    let emails: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeUnretainedValue()

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0) { //here check if have email

 let name: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue()
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(name)!=nil){//Here try check if have name, but this is incorrect form to do this ...
```

How can I check if this have name, or last name?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Type Int does not conform protocol NSLiteralConvertible.' But if I use == 0 for check if haven't name I get a crash when I execute this.

Comment: There isn't any form to check if a contact haven't first name?